# How to manage duplicate tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are a couple of tags now for Lubricant

- lube
- lubricant
- lubericant (my spelling mistake).

For starters, how can I delete the 'lubericant' tag.

And how do we manage tags of different name but same meaning (lube/lubricant)? An ideal solution would be to link tags in a tag management page, so if someone searches for questions tagged lube, they would also get questions tagged lubricant.

Same story with seat/saddle

Comment: I've noticed we also have lock/locks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try to use the 'proper', most-specific name when it comes to duplicate tags, e.g.:

- lube -> lubricant
- seat -> saddle
- disk-brake -> disc-brake

Some tags seem a little redundant:

- bike-routes -> routes
- bike-fit -> fit
- bike -> ...

I'm a bit undecided on plurals/non-plurals.. anyone have an opinion?

Comment: I don't think you will stop people using plurals, etc. so we just need to merge tags as they are noticed.  But I guess we will have to wait until some users have the required reputation to merge tags.

Comment: +1 for the use of 'proper' terms - the shortened versions may  well be region specific in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

just correct the typo to the correct spelling.
there are ways of joining tags together such as disc and disk which are alternate spellings, however you need about 2000 reputation, which will take a bit to get a few users at that level, perhaps it should be much lower during the private beta... but it can wait, and will be corrected as the site grows and people get the reputation points

Answer (score 1):

I think another merge is needed in terms of:

- tire
- tires
- tyre
- tyres

I'm not sure if the plural of tyres has been used yet.

I've retagged a couple of posts from gear to equipment to try and avoid confusion too.

There will probably come a need at some point for a merge of dérailleur and derailler (or however it's spelt in the US).

Comment: derailer in the US: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer.html